# Trying to make use of Akka future and play promises in my Play2 application

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, akka, actor, promise

When reading up on the play2 documentation I found this:

> Because of the way Play 2.0 works, action code must be as fast as
>   possible (i.e. non blocking). So what should we return as result if we
>   are not yet able to compute it? The response should be a promise of a
>   result!

Wow! This of course made me interested in [playakka](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaAkka) and [akka](http://resources.typesafe.com/docs/console/).
I'm currently building an autocomplete application that is integrating with elasticsearch,
so this would be a perfect fit!

**Controller:**

```
public class AutoComplete extends Controller {

    @BodyParser.Of(value = BodyParser.Json.class)
    public static Result complete(final String term) {

        F.Promise<List<String>> list = Akka.future(new Callable<List<String>>() {
            public List<String> call() throws Exception {
                List<String> list = IndexService.find(term);
                return list;
            }
        });    

        return async(list.map(new F.Function<List<String>, Result>() {
            @Override
            public Result apply(List<String> list) throws Throwable {
                return ok(Json.toJson(list));
            }
        }));
}
```

**Service:**

```
public static List<String> find(final String term) {

        IndexQuery < SearchWord > query = SearchWord.find.query();
        query.setQuery("{\n" +
                "    \"bool\": {\n" +
                "        \"should\": [\n" +
                "            {\n" +
                "                \"text\": {\n" +
                "                    \"search_word.ngrams\": {\n" +
                "                        \"operator\": \"and\",\n" +
                "                        \"query\": \""+term+"\"\n" +
                "                    }\n" +
                "                }\n" +
                "            },\n" +
                "            {\n" +
                "                \"text\": {\n" +
                "                    \"search_word.full\": {\n" +
                "                        \"boost\": 1,\n" +
                "                        \"query\": \""+term+"\"\n" +
                "                    }\n" +
                "                }\n" +
                "            }\n" +
                "        ]\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "}");
        IndexResults<SearchWord> indexResults = SearchWord.find.search(query);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(SearchWord word : indexResults.getResults()){
            list.add(word.getWord());
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

**SearchWord:**

```
@IndexType(name = "search_word")
public class SearchWord extends Index {

    // Find method static for request
    public static Index.Finder<SearchWord> find = new Index.Finder<SearchWord>(SearchWord.class);

    public enum WordType {
        NAME,
        STRONG_SEARCH_WORD,
        WEAK_SEARCH_WORD,
        BANNED
    }

    private String word;
    private WordType wordType;

    public SearchWord() {
    }

    public SearchWord(IndexWord indexWord) {
        super.id = ""+indexWord.getId();
        this.word = StringUtils.lowerCase(indexWord.getWord());
        this.wordType = WordType.valueOf(indexWord.getType());
    }

    public String getId() {
        return super.id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        super.id = id;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public WordType getWordType() {
        return wordType;
    }

    public void setWordType(WordType wordType) {
        this.wordType = wordType;
    }

    @Override
    public Map toIndex() {
        HashMap map = new HashMap();
        map.put("id", super.id);
        map.put("word", word);
        map.put("word_type", wordType.toString());
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public Indexable fromIndex(Map map) {
        if (map == null) {
            return this;
        }
        this.word = (String) map.get("word");
        this.wordType = WordType.valueOf((String)map.get("word_type"));
        return this;
    }


}
```

The code works very well but I must say that I'm not that sure that I have implemented this correctly. I'm really struggling to understand the documentation.
So my questions are basically:

1. Have I implemented the Future and Promise correctly?
2. Would it be better to create a custom actor, and in that actor perform the index
   search, like the example in the docs:

=====

```
 return async(
        Akka.asPromise(ask(myActor,"hello", 1000)).map(
          new Function<Object,Result>() {
            public Result apply(Object response) {
              return ok(response.toString());
            }
          }
        )
      );
```

3. Maybe you have some great example that I have not found yet?

Comment: The only questions I would have are (a) what is the advantage of asynchronous code in the case of auto-complete? (b) would any significant processor activity be blocked in the absence of asynchronous code? and (c) do you take measures against promises being resolved in the wrong order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, your code is totally ok.

I may be wrong, but I think that the second option is strictly equivalent to the first one, since the `Akka.future()` method is a wrapper around the `Akka.promise()` method.

From the [Akka class source code of Play 2.0.4](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.0.4/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/libs/Akka.java#L34):

```
/**
 * Executes a block of code asynchronously in the application Akka Actor system.
 */
public static <T> Promise<T> future(java.util.concurrent.Callable<T> callable) {
    return asPromise(akka.dispatch.Futures.future(callable, system().dispatcher()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you have correctly implemented the Promise and Future, i wouldn't consider this code to be "non-blocking"...

It seems that the blocking call is

```
List<String> list = IndexService.find(term);
```

and although this is now wrapped in a promise/future, it is still a blocking call...
If you want to be truly non-blocking (with all its benefits), you'll have to make your data access (queries) non-blocking...

Oh, and a non-blocking action method should return a Promise of a Result, not a Result...

This is how i should write your code:

```
@BodyParser.Of(value = BodyParser.Json.class)
public static F.Promise<Result> complete(final String term) {    
    scala.concurrent.Future<List<String>> listFuture = IndexService.find(term);

    F.Promise<List<String>> listPromise = F.Promise.wrap(listFuture);

    return listPromise.map(new F.Function<List<String>, Result>() {
       @Override
       public Result apply(List<String> list) throws Throwable {
          return ok(Json.toJson(list));
       }
    });
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oops, only just noticed this was asked over a year ago... thought it was just 5 days old ;-)